# How tell to maven don't bring test dependencies

Tags: maven

I have Maven dependencies with scope test.
I add flag `Dmaven.test.skip=true` but Maven still brings test dependencies.
Is there a way not to bring test dependencies if I want to build only the production part?

Comment: Please post the POM, or relevant parts of it.

Comment: What do you mean by `still brings test dependencies`?

Comment: `<dependency>
        <groupId>group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>missed.artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>` In build I get error `Could not find artifact group.id:missed.artifact:jar:tests:1.0`

Comment: that artifact need to be in a repository (at least in the local one). If you have the sources do a "mvn install" on that project. Otherwise make sure its in a maven repository configured in the settings.xml

Comment: Why I need test dependencies if I don't want compile test part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how maven works - it First tries to check that ako dependencies are available, no matter their scope. Only then it continues to test phase to find out that tests should not be executed.

A possible workaround is to define your test dependencies in a separate test maven profile, which is not applied when you do not want to run tests. Profiles are resolved before any dependence are downloaded, therefore if test dependencies are not added by the profile to the effective pom, they are not downloaded at all.

Answer (score 2):

the flag `-Dmaven.test.skip` will only skip compilation and execution of your tests within the project you run.

Its often better to use `-DskipTests` as this will compile the test classes but not run them.  See [surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) documentation.

This has nothing to do with dependencies. Those are loaded into the classpath depending on their scope and what plugins require. The surefire plugin requires resolution of scope test as it runs the unit tests.

If there are dependencies of scope test which you do not want to use you need to remove them or exclude them if they come in via transitive dependencies (dependencies of dependencies). You can execute a `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out why jar are in the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you add some dependencies for test scope, maven will first check if the dependency is available or not then it checks the scope.

You can create a maven profile, add test dependencies under the profile and trigger the profile when `-Dmaven.test.skip` or `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` option is not present. In this way you can keep your build command unchanged.

You can check this simple project [manage-test-dependencies-in-maven-the-proper-way](https://github.com/soumya-banerjee13/maven-multi-module-test-dependencies) to understand it better.